# Avoid word break while using vw for font size

Tags: css, fonts, font-size

Does there exist a mathematical relation between the **font-size** and the **screen width** so that there is no word break during resize of the width of the viewport/window?

For example, if I set the font size of a paragraph to `16px`, where the first line of the paragraph reads-

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.

If I were to resize the width of my viewport, there would be a word break in case if the viewport width is small to accommodate the sentence because the font-size is set in `px`units.

Now since the font-size increases/decreases during resize of width of viewport if the unit is set in `vw`, I want to make sure there is no word break, imagine you're resizing an image with text on it. Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Someone can override your font-size settings, and many browsers have a default minimum font-size value, so chances are your actual problem isn't going to be solved in this manner.

Comment: This is not a problem, I want to achieve this

Comment: you'd have to include your exact text in that "mathematical relationship" too.  So you'd have to go about measuring the length of that text at various font sizes in order to determine the proportion.  If you're using a fixed-width font, there might be more of a direct correlation, but it still depends on how many characters are in your text.

Comment: Could this be solved with using an SVG? text element in svg image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your container to a specific `vw` width, and then set your font-size to a specific `vw` value. With those two things, resizes should work as you expect, *provided* the font is loaded explicitly, rather than relying on "whatever font the browser decides to use", so no CSS `serif`, but also no CSS `"Times New Roman"` because you don't know which version of that font will end up actually getting used, and so you cannot trust that the font metrics are what you need them to be. So:

1. load a specific font through an `@font-face` rule
2. make sure your container is set to have a width expressed in `vw`
3. make sure your container specifies its font-size in `vw` units.

CSS:

```
.rs {
  width: 50vw;
  background: lightgreen;
  font-family: lato;
  font-size: 3.3vw;
}
```

HTML:

```
....
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" 
<div class="rs">
  This is text This is text This is text T
</div>
```

Live example: http://jsbin.com/januxevebe/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Ah! That's amazing! I did a mistake of setting the width in `px` instead of `vw` This is exactly what I wanted! Upvoted!